# How to solve duplicate rownames error on R

Tags: r

I know this has been asked several times but I've tried a lot of solutions as suggested before and they don't work. I keep getting the below error on R (no matter however I modify the csv file) when I run the below

```
annotation_file <- "Best3_Abicinctus_FunctionalAnnotation.csv"
annotation_info <- read.csv(annotation_file, row.names=1, header=T)
Error in read.table(file=file,header=header,sep=sep,quote=quote, : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

I cannot set 'row.names=NULL' as this will screw up the data order for what I intend to do downstream. I even removed blanks/tabs from the end of every row by using `sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`but the error doesnt go away. I tested replacing commas and spaces in all of the column entries and yet the annoying error doesn't go away. This is how first few lines of the file look like

```
"gene_id","name","product"
"maker-Contig673-pred_gff_AUGUSTUS-gene-1.6","stk10","Serine/threonine-protein kinase 10"
"maker-Contig204-pred_gff_AUGUSTUS-gene-3.1","ccnh","Cyclin-H"
"maker-Contig31958-pred_gff_AUGUSTUS-gene-0.7","fam136a","Protein FAM136A"
"maker-Contig31340-pred_gff_AUGUSTUS-gene-0.8","h2b","Histone H2B"
```

The file is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wta8k1rdrwqo8fx/Best3_Abicinctus_FunctionalAnnotation.csv?dl=0) on Dropbox in case you would like to take a look. I'm on a deadline and I'm just helplessly stuck at this step. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: By using `row.names=1` you are telling `read.csv` to use the `gene_id`-column as rownames. Looking at the first few lines, I can imagine that not all names are unique. Do you really want the `gene_id` to become rownames instead of an actual column in your dataset?

Comment: Yes cos' in the downstream steps, I run the following: sig_de_annotations <- annotation_info[rownames(sig_de_results),]
sig_de_results<-cbind(sig_de_annotations, as.data.frame(sig_de_results))
write.csv(sig_de_results, row.names=T, file="DEGlist_Deformed_vs_Healthy.csv",)

Comment: The sig_de_results contain the gene_id in its first column i.e., "maker-Contigxxx"

Comment: I think you will have to update your script because dealing with multiple rownames is not good practice. I suggest you keep `row.names = NULL` and adapt `sig_de_annotations <- annotation_info[which(annotation_info$gene_id %in% rownames(sig_de_results)),]` or something similar

Comment: Thanks @BastienDucreux for the updated script but the script seems to be screwing up the gene order in the final csv file

Comment: Could you add some details about "downstream steps" you want to perform? It is usally a lot easier to store your data in a column than trying to deal with rownames problems. For the gene order you could use functions such as `dplyr::arrange` to sort your dataframe

Comment: Thanks for your response @Paul. I have a list of significantly up/down-regulated gene_ids after performing DESeq2 along with other columns such as p-value and so on stored in sig_de_results and I just want to annotate those gene_ids (e.g.,""maker-Contigxxx") in sig_de_results to the gene name info present on "Best3_Abicinctus_FunctionalAnnotation.csv".

Comment: and this is the R code I use to achieve this annotation `sig_de_annotations <- annotation_info[rownames(sig_de_results),] sig_de_results<-cbind(sig_de_annotations, as.data.frame(sig_de_results)) write.csv(sig_de_results, row.names=T, file="DEGlist_Deformed_vs_Healthy.csv",)`

Comment: Thanks but that does not make your example reproducible. Please edit your question with a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it will help us a lot to figure out how to help you. I.e. currently, we do not have enough to make the `sig_annotations` and `sig_results` objects

Comment: `gene_id` definitely should be a column and not rowname. How does making it a column screw up the order?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing the duplicate gene ids in column 1 of the annotation file "Best3_Abicinctus_FunctionalAnnotation.csv". Earlier I had tested by only removing the duplicate rows. Thank you @Jaap for the hint and also to the other users for their various suggestions.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.